# Can we setup dual monitor with a graphic card that had displayport and HDMI?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, displayport

I'm looking at "Gigabyte Geforce GTX 1050 2GB GDDR5 128 Bit PCI-E Graphic Card (GV-N1050OC-2GD)". It has 1 display port, 1 hdmi, and 1 DVI.

After googling around, I can't find out if I can use 1 display port and 1 hdmi to setup dual monitors (HP 27ea). Most of the answers (I've found on google) used HDMI and DVI. I don't understand why.

Could you someone explain why (or how) HDMI + DVI is better than HDMI + Displayport?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't, but most people don't have DP-cables at home, while nearly everyone has some HDMI and at least one DVI-cable.
It shouldn't be a problem to use it for dual-monitor-setups - in fact, each connector should have its own signal output, meaning you could even have three independent monitors.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this spec](http://www8.hp.com/emea_middle_east/en/products/monitors/product-detail.html?oid=13086687#!tab=specs) the HP27ea has one VGA and two HDMI ports so you need an adapter/cable for either DVI or DP to HDMI to connect two Monitors to the Gigabyte Geforce GTX 1050

I don't see any problem with that configuration independent from the (not mentioned) OS.